# Java cryptography routine to run under both Java SE and Android class libraries

Tags: java, android, algorithm, encryption

I am wanting to write a cryptographic routine in Java that can be run under *both* the standard Java class libraries and the Android ones. The routine is for encrypting/decrypting byte arrays using a password-based key and a standard symmetric cipher (such as AES).
Here is the nub of what I have in mind:

```
static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 10_000;
static final byte[] SALT = {37, -19, . . . 88, 0, 127, 3, 82};
static final PBEParameterSpec PBE_PARAM_SPEC = 
    new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, ITERATION_COUNT);
static final String ALGORITHM = "PBEwithSHAand128bitAES-CBC-BC";

char[] passwordChars = “SECRET!”.toCharArray();

PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChars);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
SecretKey pbeKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
Cipher encryptingCipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
encryptingCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, PBE_PARAM_SPEC);
Cipher decryptingCipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
decryptingCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, PBE_PARAM_SPEC);

byte[] plainBytesIn = . . . the message to be encrypted . . .

byte[] cipherBytes = encryptingCipher.doFinal(plainBytesIn);

byte[] plainBytesOut = decryptingCipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
```

I found that this routine runs fine under Android, but fails under Java SE.

The reason for this is that I selected the particular algorithm used (ie, Password-Based Encryption using SHA and 128-bit AES with Cipher-Block-Chaining) from the list of algorithm names generated by the following routine while running under Android:

```
void listProviders() {
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
        log(provider.getName());
        for (String key : provider.stringPropertyNames()) {
            log("\t" + key + "\t" + provider.getProperty(key));
        }
    }
}
```

However, when run under Java SE, I found that it generates a list of algorithm names that seem to be quite different. In particular, the above algorithm (“PBEwith...”) does not appear to be available under Java SE – thus causing the encryption routine to fail.

Is there an algorithm (possibly under different names in each list) available for *both* libraries? (I am not too bothered about the precise details of the algorithm: it just has to be strong enough for routine  low-value commercial use.) If not,  is it difficult to put together ones own overall encryption algorithm from the basic  components provided by the  javax.crypto  libraries?

Comment: You should be aware that not even all Android devices have the same set of algorithms.  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/12/changes-to-secretkeyfactory-api-in.html